# How do I store different types that implement the same trait in a vector and call common functions on them?

Tags: polymorphism, rust, traits

I'm learning Rust and I'm having difficulties in implementing polymorphism. I want to use an array to store either `Circle` or `Test`.

```
trait Poli {
    fn area(&self) -> f64;
}

struct Circle {
    x:      f64,
    y:      f64,
    radius: f64,
}

impl Circle {
    fn new (xx: f64, yy: f64, r: f64) -> Circle{
        Circle{ x: xx, y: yy, radius: r }
    }
}

impl Poli for Circle {
   fn area(&self) -> f64 {
       std::f64::consts::PI * (self.radius * self.radius)
   }
}

struct Test {
    x:      f64,
    y:      f64,
    radius: f64,
    test:   f64,
}

impl Test {
    fn new (xx: f64, yy: f64, r: f64, t: f64) -> Circle{
        Test{ x: xx, y: yy, radius: r, test: t, }
    }
}

impl Poli for Test {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        std::f64::consts::PI * (self.radius * self.radius)
    }
}
```

I do not know how to make a vector to store types with the same `trait`:

```
let cir  = Circle::new(10f64, 10f64, 10f64);
let test = Test::new(10f64, 10f64, 10f64, 10f64);

//let mut vec: Vec<Poli> = Vec::new();   <---
```

I'd like to iterate the vector and call functions from the trait. Is there any way to do this, or some alternative?

I read [the trait object documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html) but I think it's not what I want.

Comment: I don't think this really warrants a full answer, but: trait objects are *exactly* what you want here (assuming you want open polymorphism).  If closed is acceptable, you want an `enum`.  If there's some aspect of that chapter that you don't understand, or you can explain *why* you think that's not a good solution, it might improve the question to add that in.

Comment: @DK. sorry for my English, I did not say never -> why you think that's not a good solution ... just saying I was reading this page and I could not find what I was looking for. it turns out that if it was on the page, but I could not understand well the examples to apply what I was looking for. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [page you linked to](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html#dynamic-dispatch), you'll need to either store the `Poli` implementing structs as `Vec<&Poli>` or `Vec<Box<Poli>>` depending on whether you want to own the values or just store a reference:

```
// Owned
let circle = Circle::new(10f64, 10f64, 10f64);
let test = Test::new(10f64, 10f64, 10f64, 10f64);

let polis = vec![Box::new(circle) as Box<Poli>, Box::new(test) as Box<Poli>];

for poli in polis {
    println!("{}", poli.area());
}

// Reference
let circle = Circle::new(10f64, 10f64, 10f64);
let test = Test::new(10f64, 10f64, 10f64, 10f64);

let polis = vec![&circle as &Poli, &test as &Poli];

for poli in polis {
    println!("{}", poli.area());
}
```

Output

```
314.1592653589793
314.1592653589793
314.1592653589793
314.1592653589793
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=17cf00c3af1ba3c2a444c54c20444f8f&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: I get "the trait `Poli` cannot be made into an object"

Answer (score 0):

After [Dogbert's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357995/polymorphism-trait-vector-common-functions#36358200), I played a bit and found this way works for me. I am new to Rust and I do not know if this is obvious, but I'll leave it here to help others.

```
let circle = Circle::new(10f64, 10f64, 10f64);
let test   = Test::new(10f64, 10f64, 10f64, 10f64);

let mut vec: Vec<&Poli> = Vec::<&Poli>::new();
    vec.push(&circle);
    vec.push(&test);

for v in vec {
    println!("new {}", v.area());
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ad6e8934a3134e9899b6d7f7dcf3d840&version=stable)

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify the exact type twice: you can either remove `: Vec<&Poli>` or `::<&Poli>`.